# How Can I create multiple schema if not exist in db

Tags: postgresql, gradle, flyway

I am using gradle . I want to create a multiple schema in `postgreSQL` but `flywayInit` is not working as this command is removed.

I edited my `build.gradle` file like this

```
flyway {
    url = dataAccessDbUrl
    user = dataAccessDbUsername
    password = dataAccessDbPassword
    schemas = ['metadata', 'testDb']
}
```

I want to keep migration table in separate schema.

How can I achieve this?